# extract minutes from a date php

Tags: php, date

I'm creating a PHP website and I have to test a date to know if minutes == 00, 15, 30 or 45

To enter the date I use a datetime-local input in the HTML form.

Unfortunately when I try to get the minutes it always returns "33"

Here is my code :

```
$d=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date_deb));
echo $d.'<br />'.date(i,$d);
```

it returns:

```
2013-08-18 12:05:00
33
```

Comment: Did you read the manual for date? it takes a timestamp, which `$d` isn't

Comment: Yes, I read it but that's the purpose of my question, I couldn't find a way to change the type

Comment: When the date is in a fixed format anyway, it's trivial and likely faster not to use `date` and `strtotime` at all but just to extract the substring at the minute position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use the `date` function again. Just use:

```
echo date('i', strtotime($date_deb));
```

Comment: Might be good to add a note about the fact that he is using an undefined constant `i` instead of the string `'i'`.

Comment: for the 'i' it's a mistake when I wrote the question but Bora's answer works.   Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

There is reason why you got 33, it's mainly because your passed a date time string into the `date` function second param. it expects a `since epoch seconds` value.

you can get the value you need from the first statement it self.

```
$d=date('i', strtotime($date_deb));
```